# how to get the closest left or right <li> id from a specified <li> inside a <ul> in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my html structure

```
<ul id="slider_donor" class="clearfix">
  <li id="slider_3">
  <li id="slider_4">
  <li id="slider_5">
  <li id="active-slide" class="active-slide">
  <li id="slider_6">
  <li id="slider_1">
  <li id="slider_2">
</ul>
```

Now I want to get the `id` closest to `<li id="active-slide" class="active-slide">` form `left` or from `right` .

That means from `left` `id` should be  `slider_5` and from right it should be `slider_6`

Comment: So many correct answers dont know which one to accept :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.next()` or `.prev()`:

```
 $('#active-slide').prev().prop('id'); // slider_5
 $('#active-slide').next().prop('id'); // slider_6
```

- [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
- [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)
- [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.active-slide').next().attr('id');
$('.active-slide').prev().attr('id');
```

Answer (score 2):

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rSk73/)

use `.next()` and `.prev()`

```
$('.active-slide').next().css('background-color','red');
$('.active-slide').prev().css('background-color','green');

<ul id="slider_donor" class="clearfix">
    <li id="slider_3">xx</li>
  <li id="slider_4">xx</li>
  <li id="slider_5">xx</li>
  <li id="active-slide" class="active-slide">xx</li>
  <li id="slider_6">xx</li>
  <li id="slider_1">xx</li>
  <li id="slider_2">xx</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use .prev('li') and .next('li') selector for that
```

https://api.jquery.com/prev/

http://api.jquery.com/next/

```
$('active-slide').prev('li').prop('id'); // slider_5
 $('#active-slide').next('li').prop('id'); // slider_6
```

Answer (score 0):

.prev and .next are your friend.

```
var leftId, rightId, left, right;
var left = $(".active-slide").prev("li");
var right = $(".active-slide").next("li");
if (left.length > 0) {
  leftId = left.attr("id");
}
if (right.length > 0) {
  rightId = right.attr("id");
}
```